There seem (to be)
Seem can mean "to give the impression of existing; appear t̲o̲ ̲b̲e̲", especially with the existential pronoun there (e.g., there seems no need for all this nonsense).
What governs the inclussion/omission of "to be" in a sentence such as there doesn't/don't seem (to be) any left.
Secondly,

Isn't this just to-be–deletion (I'd say fairly unusual after there seems/doesn't seem except with 'no need')?
